# vector vs valarray

Tags: c++

Зачем нужен `std::vector<>`, если есть потенциально более быстрый `std::valarray<>`?

Comment: а итераторами в valarray как вы будете пользоваться? Это как минимум.

Comment: @Sublihim есть глобальные `begin` и `end`

Comment: valarray больше оптимизирован под работу с числовыми последовательностями, поддерживая операторы умножения и т.д. Для остального юзать valarray - не рекомендуется.

Comment: @Sublihim почему?

Comment: кстати: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580628/valarray-vs-vector-why-was-valarray-introduced

Comment: @Sublihim _They are not designed to avoid pointers. C++11 defines begin() and end() in valarray that return iterators to them_

Comment: а смысл городить "велосипед" :)

Comment: дело в том, что в каких-то случаях лучше использовать valarray в каких-то вектор.

Comment: @Sublihim мне как раз хочется почитать про эти случаи в ответах

Comment: в целом случая два: 1. У вас неизменяемая числовая последовательность, с которой вы хотите быстро работать (складывать, умножать и т.д.) - вы используете valarray 2. В остальных случаях - вектор, т.к. у него есть пушбэки (с оптимальной работой памятью в ресайзе, вдобавок вы можете запихать свой аллокатор в вектор), не костыльные итераторы и т.д.

Comment: у `valarray` деструктивный `resize`. Он не является динамическим массивом в полном смысле.

Answer (score 7):

Упомянутые классы используются для разных задач.

[`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) для хранения последовательности **любых однотипных элементов** и обеспечения возможности изменения размера:

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size.

[`std::valarray`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/) для хранения массива **значений** и выполнения **математических** операций над ними.

> A valarray object is designed to hold an array of values, and easily perform mathematical operations on them.

Выполняемые операции над объектами `valarray` могут быть оптимизированы в конкретных реализациях, например, для обеспечения параллельных вычислений.

Т.о. если ваша задача - обработка чисел, то смысл использовать `std::valarray` есть. Если же нужно иметь контейнер объектов, не являющихся по сути математическими значениями, то использовать `std::vector` (или любой другой [подходящий контейнер](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/194726/)).